# Prevent maximized applications flowing over my app

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a window always stay on top in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683330/how-to-make-a-window-always-stay-on-top-in-net)
>   [Creating a .NET app that “docks” to the side of the screen and limits other windows' sizes when maximized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510065/creating-a-net-app-that-docks-to-the-side-of-the-screen-and-limits-other-wind)

I have a C# Winforms application that runs similarly to the menu bar on a Mac. It's only 24 pixels high, is the full width of the screen, located at the top and should be the top most application.

However, when I run other applications and maximize them, they go under my application and I cannot see the control bar (icon, name, minimize, maximize and close buttons) for them. What I would like is for other maximized applications to maximize to just under my application, so I can still see the other applications control bar.

Is there a way to prevent other applications from doing this, and getting them to maximize under my application?

Thanks,
Karl

Comment: Try setting `Form.TopMost = true`, but if you're running on Mac with `mono` then it can be very tricky

Comment: I've already set form.TopMost = true, but it made no difference.

Comment: Read this and understand how it applies to your case: [*What if two programs did this?*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Richard. I understand what the post is saying, but I guess I'm trying to prevent two applications from using the same space, and forcing any other applications to ignore the desktop real estate used by my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [Creating a .NET app that "docks" to the side of the screen and limits other windows' sizes when maximized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510065/creating-a-net-app-that-docks-to-the-side-of-the-screen-and-limits-other-wind). Please note that the link to the C# version of the code is dead. Here are the relevant, working links:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6741/AppBar-using-C

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144177(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If you think a question is a duplicate, leave a comment and flag the question as a duplicate. It's not necessary or desirable to answer it.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Thanks.